# Cloning the Photo.app?

Tags: ios

I need to have a scrollview or just a regular view of thumbnail images of images that are in the resources folder of my app. And when the user touches the thumbnail, it will show a different view with the touched image in full size. How would I accomplish this? Are there any tutorials, or easy ways to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`KTPhotoBrowser`](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend the [three20 library](http://three20.info/). Specifically, [TTPhotoView](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_photo_view.php)

I found [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) useful